# PHP Date - Convert from Wed Sep 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date that is passed to PHP as such:

$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Date"]);

The date displays like this - Wed Sep 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
Output needed - 2013-09-10

Comment: By the way, as John Conde said, you should not use `mysql_real_escape_string` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dt = new DateTime('Wed Sep 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.org/1JGItTG7)**

Comment: Ahh I see, new DateTime was the key to this puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Date"]);
// You should not use mysql_real_escape_string here.

$date = 'Wed Sep 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: You could have removed it. :)

Comment: Yes, I left a comment to him, tks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Date"]);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```